Organize video stream files into folders
ffmpeg -i {file} -deadline good -movflags +faststart -map_metadata -1 
        -c:a libopus -c:v libvpx-vp9 -pix_fmt yuv420p 
        -map 0:a:0 -b:a:0 128k 
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:0 scale=-1:144 
        -map 0:v:0 -filter:v:1 scale=-1:240 
        -dash_segment_type webm 
        -seg_duration 4 
        -init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
        -media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$" 
        -adaptation_sets "id=0, streams=v id=0, streams=a id=1" 
        -f dash /manifest.mpd

Is it possible to organize video streams into folders?
In the example there are 2 video streams, one is 144, the second is 240. How can you specify in
    -init_seg_name "init-$RepresentationID$.$ext$"
    -media_seg_name "sg-$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.$ext$"

What is one way for the first flow, another for the second??
For example, the folder name is the frame height of the video stream
